# Implications of too big TEMP tablespace?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, tablespace

What potential problems can occur in Oracle DB, when using too large temporary table space, except as unreasonably large consumption of disk space?

Comment: Why do you think it can cause any problems? Do you have something in mind, or some behaviour you think might be cause by this? [You can shrink it if you want to reclaim some space](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17120/tspaces007.htm#CFHJFBB), but that doesn't seem to be what you want.

Comment: Im worried that any performance degradation can occur.

Comment: Periodically there is a situation of lack of space in the temporary table space (ora 01652), while there is a relatively large amount of free disk space and I can give it to a temp. Also Ive no doubt  (generally) about optimality of queries.

Comment: I still think that making a way too large tablespace is a very good method of determining what size your typical database (usage) suits best. This would imply that afterwards you would decrease the size, relevant to the max size seen. Only issue could be : very bad code, resulting in huge temp usage. But, you don't have bad code, do you ? Maybe you do, resulting in posting the initial question. The fix for bad code would be obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A large temporary tablespace will not cause any performance issues.  I've tuned SQL on databases with more than a terabyte of temporary tablespace and never seen any issues caused by that space.